# how to implement jquery for mobile devices ?

Tags: jquery, placeholder

I am trying to change my jquery so when the screen res is below 480px the placeholder text changes.

so the current text is "what are you looking for"

below 480px the text needs to say "Search me "

Thanks a million.

here is my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rK6S3/)

```
//Search form typing

var txt = "What are you Searching for?";
var timeOut;
var txtLen = txt.length;
var char = 0;
$('.main-search').attr('placeholder', '|');
(function typeIt() {
    var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        $('.main-search').attr('placeholder', type + '|');
        typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            $('.main-search').attr('placeholder', $('.main-search').attr('placeholder').slice(0, -1)) // remove the '|'
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, humanize);
}());
```

Comment: Just measure `$(window).width()`. Better yet, use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to show one element and hide the other.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case for CSS media queries. Hide the element that contains the "what are you looking for" text below 480px, and show the "Search me" text. Do the opposite if larger than 480px. No need for JavaScript at all here. You would be hitting a thumb tack with a sledge hammer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution buddy : http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/8yAy5/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).resize(function(){
if($(window).width() < 480)
{
    $("input").attr("value", "Search me");
}
    else
    {
        $("input").attr("value", "What do you want to search?");
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. the only problem is that it doesnt work when you land on 480px or below pixels, As in Mobile devices?

Comment: Is you website opening in the desktop format in mobiles?